# How do I make Ajax.ActionLink update an element instead of navigating the whole page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I am trying to update a `<div>` in my view when the user clicks on an `Ajax.ActionLink`.  However, it always navigates the entire page rather than inserting the server's response into the element I specify.

I feel like I'm doing everything in [this example](http://blogger.forgottenskies.com/?p=234), but even after creating the simplest test case I still can't create the behavior I want.

In the test case that follows, I load `/Company/test` and after clicking on "Go!", I expected the `<div>` to be replaced with "All done", but instead the whole page navigates to `/Company/test_ajax`.

I'm sure I'm missing something here.  Thanks in advance.

**CompanyController**

```
public ActionResult test()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult test_ajax()
{
    return Content("All done");
}
```

**test.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>test</h2>
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Go!", "test_ajax",
    new AjaxOptions {
        UpdateTargetId="viewport"
        }) %>
<div id="viewport">Replace me!</div>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example works as expected on my computer. Check if files MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.js are really present in ../../Scripts folder.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was my problem.  I had problems getting the right sources for scripts and styles unless I used the Url.Content("~/project/path/script.js") syntax.

Comment: For MVC3 and higher use "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"

Answer (score 6):

If You are using MVC 3 you will have to include "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" as a reference. It should already be present in your Scripts folder. \m/

Answer (score 4):

I have found that adding jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js to my layout.cshtml page avoids all sorts of stupid *"why does this not work?"* moments when working with ajax objects/methods.

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify the AjaxOptions in my ActionLink call to get it working:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Update", "UpdateContent", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "target", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })%>
```

Comment: This did not work for me:
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Go!", "test_ajax", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod="Post", UpdateTargetId="viewport", InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace} ) %>

Answer (score 1):

Had problem with this too. I'm using VS2013 and jquery-1.10.2.min.js. Had to use a combination of 4 js files to get it to work. Hope this sample code helps someone.

Test.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>test</title>

        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.history.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $.history.init(function (hash) {
                if (hash.length > 0) {
                    $("#" + hash).click();
                }
            },
            { unescape: ",/" });
        });

        function AddHashTag(hashTag) {
            window.location.hash = hashTag;
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Render Circle", "GetCircle", null,
                new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get", UpdateTargetId = "divContent", OnSuccess = "AddHashTag('circle')" },
                new { @id = "circle" })

            @Ajax.ActionLink("Render Diamond", "GetDiamond", null,
                new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get", UpdateTargetId = "divContent", OnSuccess = "AddHashTag('diamond')" },
                new { @id = "diamond" })

            @Ajax.ActionLink("Render Star", "GetStar", null,
                new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get", UpdateTargetId = "divContent", OnSuccess = "AddHashTag('star')" },
                new { @id = "star" })

        <div id="divContent" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 50px 50px;">
        </div>
</body>
</html>


star.cshtml:
star<div class="star"></div>

diamond.cshtml:
diamond<div class="diamond"></div>

circle.cshtml:
circle<div class="circle"></div>


Home Controller:

        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetCircle()
        {
            return PartialView("Circle");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetDiamond()
        {
            return PartialView("Diamond");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetStar()
        {
            return PartialView("Star");
        }
```

Comment: This one should have more thumbs up, it solved my issue! However, I just needed these 2: @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")